# Thumbnails of images larger then 4096px are not displayed in file selection dialog

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

In file selection dialog (for instance, in Firefox when trying to upload an image), thumbnail of images larger than 4096px are not displayed (on the right of the windows). I would like to known if a parameter exist to increase this limit ? I found a parameter to increase the image weight limit (10Mb by default) but no parameter for the image dimensions. Furthermore, I specify that this limit exist only in file selection dialog but not in the files manager.

Thank you for any help.

**Note:** I found this limit by empirical tests : I resized a large image in different dimensions and with 4096px of width, the thumbnail is displayed and with 4097px of width, it's not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1500221) :

> Turns out firefox uses its own mechanism for previews and indeed the limitation by image size is hardcoded there (only images < 4096px).

**Note:** the limit was introduced [in 2015](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/commit/0c7ff089845268703d1281a3fb389cfe6aac5506).